# How to read bits from std::bitset in a sliding window fashion and convert them to int?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitset

I have `std::bitset`, where first `n` bits are set to some values. For each `index` in `std::bitset`, I want to read `m` bits (`m < n`) and convert them to `int`. When `(index + m) > n`, I want to wrap around.

**For example**, for `n = 6` and `m = 2`:

```
std::bitset<8> my_bits {0b00101101}; // out of 8 bits, first 6 are set
// bit indexes            76543210
```

For each bit `index` in `my_bits` I want to take 2 bits at a time and convert them to `int`:

```
ind 0: 10 -> 1
ind 1: 01 -> 2
ind 2: 11 -> 3
ind 3: 10 -> 1
ind 4: 01 -> 2
ind 5: 11 -> 3 (wrapped around)
```

Right now I have the following code, which seems to work (run it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HkFlQGyaL)). I am looking for something more elegant.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cmath>
int main() {
    const std::bitset <8> my_bits {0b00101101};
    int n = 6;
    int m = 2;

    for (int n_ind = 0; n_ind < n; ++n_ind) {

        std::cout << "ind " << n_ind << " -> ";

        int exp_2 = 0;
        int res = 0;
        for (int m_i = 0; m_i < m; ++m_i) {
            int curr_ind = (n_ind + m_i) % n; // % n is for wrap-around
            res += my_bits[curr_ind] * std::pow(2, exp_2);
            exp_2++;
        }

        std::cout << "res: " << res << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
I tried to write what Sam Varshavchik suggested, but it doesn't seem to produce the result I want, what am I doing wrong? Also, I don't know how to implement the "wrap around" in this case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    const std::bitset <8> my_bits {0b00101101};
    int n = 6;
    int m = 2;

    unsigned int mask = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        mask = (mask << 1) + 1;
    }

    int res = 0;
    for (int n_ind = 0; n_ind < n; ++n_ind) {

        int ind_t = n_ind % n;

        res <<= 1;
        res += my_bits[ind_t];
        res &= mask;

        std::cout << "ind " << ind_t << " -> ";
        std::cout << "res: " << res << std::endl;
        std::cout << "res after mask: " << std::bitset<32>(res) << std::endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The elegant solution should be very obvious once you observe the fundamental fact that if you already have `m` bits' value in `int res`, reading the next bit involves nothing more than shifting `res` left by 1, adding the next bit to `res`, and then masking off the lowest `m` bits, and now you have the next value. Only one `for` loop is needed to do all of this. Simple, isn't it? Trying to recalculate `res`, from scratch, for each starting bit position (as the shown code appears to do), is the completely wrong approach.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I updated my post trying to implement your suggestion, could you check why it is not working correctly?

Comment: `I am looking for something more elegant` would make this question opinion based..

Comment: Now I get `error: ‘ind_t’ was not declared in this scope`. Presumably it isn't working because you forgot to declare `ind_t`.

Comment: @gmatht, I removed a line and forgot to change indexing. Now it should compile. I meant that the result is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function. Encapsulate the algorithm. Accumulate results in a entity you would return. And use bitshifts instead of `std::pow`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

template<size_t N>
std::vector<int> convert_bitset_to_ints(const std::bitset<N>& bs, unsigned n, unsigned m) {
    std::vector<int> ret(n);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            ret[i] <<= 1;
            ret[i] |= bs[(i + j) % n];
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

int main() {
    const std::bitset <8> my_bits {0b00101101};
    auto v = convert_bitset_to_ints(my_bits, 6, 2);

    for (auto&& i : v) {
        std::cout << "res=" << i << " mask=" << std::bitset<2>(i) << "\n"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to show an additional solution, based on `std::string`.

Unfortunately, the `std::bitset` is not that powerfull and offers not much functionality. But, it has at least a conversion function to generate a `std::string`. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string).

With that, we immediately have the needed functionality. So, first we will construct a string (using [constructor number 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)) with the needed binary digits. To handle the wrap around, we will simple add the same string twice. Then `0b101101` will result in "101101101101".

For the result, we iterate simply over substrings of the original.

Please see the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

// Programm parameters
constexpr size_t NumberOfBits = 8U;
constexpr size_t n = 6;
constexpr size_t m = 2;

int main() {

    // The test data
    const std::bitset <NumberOfBits> myBits{ 0b00101101 };

    // Convert to binary string
    const std::string s(myBits.to_string(), NumberOfBits - n, n);

    // For easier handling of wrap-arounds we concatenate the string with itself --> 101101101101
    const std::string bitString = s + s;

    // Iterate over m-wide substrings and show converted result
    for (size_t i{}; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout << i + 1 << ".\t" << bitString.substr(i, m) << " --> " << std::stoul(bitString.substr(i, m), nullptr, 2) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

This is elegant, but not so fast. If you want to convert billions of data, I would implement a different algorithm, without using `std::bitset`